# How do I pull the middle of a string variable in batch?

Tags: string, variables, batch-file

I need to get a certain part of a string as one variable, and the rest as another variable. Ignor the "Script.CreateSub", that doesn't matter.

```
@Echo Off
Set String=Script.CreateSub(Start)
```

I need a variable named ComName to equal the first part of the input (Script.CreateSub) and a variable named Name that equals whatever is in between the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much the same answer as above but doesn't use delayed expansion, as it is not needed, and it will handle many poison characters.

```
@echo off
Set "String=Script.CreateSub(Start)"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%a in ("%String%") do set "ComName=%%a" & set "Name=%%b"
echo "%ComName%" , "%Name%"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set String=Script.CreateSub(Start)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%a in ("%String%") do set function=%%a&set param=%%b
echo function=%function%
echo param=%param%
pause
```

See http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.SplitString for more info on this technique.